# How do I use a variable with my WHERE clause in my Entity Framework query

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm running a query in my project with multiple joins. I want to provide the WHERE clause with a variable instead of hard coded as it is now but cannot seem to get the correct syntax.

```
var data = (from a in db.StudentData
            join b in db.Contacts on a.SID equals b.SID
            join c in db.Addresses on a.SID equals c.SID
            join d in db.EntryQuals.DefaultIfEmpty() on a.SID equals d.SID                            
            where a.SID == searchTxt
                  select new
                    {
                        ID = a.SID,
                        Birthdate = a.BIRTHDTE,
                        FirstName = a.FNAMES,
                        PreviousName = a.PREVSURNAME,                                
                        EntryQualAwardID = d.ENTRYQUALAWARDID,
                        AwardDate = d.AWARDDATE
       }).ToList();
```

How can I get my WHERE clause to work with a variable (ie: a.[ fieldVar ] ) where fieldVar could be "SID" as it is in the code currently.

Comment: Maybe it is just me but I cannot understand what you are looking for exactly. Are you facing an issue while execution the where clause ? What is the type of a.SID, what is the type of searchTxt ? Do you have an error message to provide ?

Comment: Supposing I want to search using another field name instead of SID, say FName. searchTxt is a variable so how do I make the field or fields I'm searching on dynamically created? JacquesB knows what I mean but his solution still requires me to create the WHERE clause using hard coded fields.

Comment: Have you tried reflection?  Something like...

where a.GetType().GetProperty(fieldVar).GetValue(a) == searchTxt ... Admittedly, not an ideal solution and can't say I've tried it, but it might get you what you need.

Comment: Which property in which context do you want to specify dynamically? My question is, using your example: do you want to specify which property will be used to compare to `b.SID`, `c.SID` and `d.SID`?

Comment: I've made a comment below which explains better. Basically I want to be able to search any one of twenty plus tables all with five to ten fields dynamically so unless I use some sort of condition for each case I need to be able to use variables for every selection made, which makes the process more generic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When dealing with user select-able search criteria you will need to code for the possible selections. When dealing with building searches I recommend using the Fluent syntax over the Linq QL syntax as it builds an expression that is easy to conditionally modify as you go.  From there you can use a Predicate & PredicateBuilder to dynamically compose your WHERE condition.

Jacques solution will work, but the downside of this approach is that you are building a rather large & complex SQL statement which conditionally applies criteria. My preference is to conditionally add the WHERE clauses in the code to ensure the SQL is only as complex as it needs to be.

If you want to do something like a smart search (think Google with one text entry to search across several possible fields)

```
var whereClause = PredicateBuilder.False<StudentData>();
int id;
DateTime date;
if(int.TryParse(searchTxt, out id))
    whereClause = whereClause.Or(x => x.SID == id);
else if(DateTime.TryParse(searchTxt, out date))
    whereClause = whereClause.Or(x => x.BirthDate == date);
else
   whereClause = whereClause.Or(x => x.FirstName.Contains(searchTxt));

var data = db.StudentData
    .Where(whereClause)
    .Select(a => new
    {
        ID = a.SID,
        Birthdate = a.BIRTHDTE,
        FirstName = a.FNAMES,
        PreviousName = a.PREVSURNAME,                                
        EntryQualAwardID = a.EntryQuals.ENTRYQUALAWARDID,
        AwardDate = a.EntryQuals.AWARDDATE
    }).ToList();
```

This does some basic evaluations of the search criteria to see if it fits the purpose of the search. I.e. if they can search by name, date, or ID and IDs are numeric, we only search on an ID if the criteria was numeric. If it looked like a date, we search by date, otherwise we search by name. (and potentially other searchable strings)

If they can search for ID, FirstName, and BirthDate and enter one or more of those as separate entry fields (Search criteria page) then based on which entries they fill in you can either pass separate nullable parameters and do the above based on what parameters are passed, or pass a list of search values with something like an Enum for which value was searched for:

I.e. by parameters:

```
private void ByParameters(int? id = null, DateTime? birthDate = null, string name = null)
{
    var whereClause = PredicateBuilder.False<StudentData>();
    if(id.HasValue)
        whereClause = whereClause.Or(x => x.SID == id.Value);
    if(date.HasValue)
    {
        DateTime dateValue = date.Value.Date;   
        whereClause = whereClause.Or(x => x.BirthDate == dateValue);
    }
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
       whereClause = whereClause.Or(x => x.FirstName.Contains(name));

    // ....
}
```

If the number of parameters starts to get big, then a custom type can be created to encapsulate the individual null-able values. I.e.:

```
[Serializable]
public class SearchCriteria
{
    public int? Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime? BirthDate { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
private void ByParameters(SearchCriteria criteria)
{
    // ....
}
```

Or you can compose a more dynamic parameter list object with a criteria type and value but it starts getting more complex than it's probably worth.

Comment: Thanks Steve, that is a great help. To completely solve my problem, say there are twenty plus selectable tables with five to ten fields per table. In your solutions above I can use conditions to work out which field and type is selected for fields. Is there no other way than to use conditions to determine which table has been selected to hard code the where clause (ie: var whereClause = PredicateBuilder.False<StudentData>();)?

Comment: As long as the entities are related (I.e. mapped with HasOne/HasMany etc.) your conditions can be applied as filters through the top-level entity reference. For instance if a StudentData has an Address and you want to give the option to filter by City then you can use `.Or(x => x.Address.City.Contains(city))` to get to the address from the student data. EF relationships are extremely powerful tools for querying and selecting relevant data without explicit joins which are more familiar when used to working with TSQL.

Answer (score 0):

You can't really do that in Linq, sine linq needs to know the the type of the field at compile time. A workaround would be something like

```
where (fieldVar=="SID" && a.SID == searchTxt) || 
      (fieldVar=="FNAMES" && a.FNAMES== searchTxt) || ...
```

This will also alert you at compile time if you are doing an illegal comparison, eg. comparing a date to a string.